# How to share publicly an Mlab Mongodb database on my website?

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a database set up with *mlab* and I would like to make it available publicly on my website so that visitors could consult it and make queries.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Better provision your application on Heroku and add mlab .
[Here](https://dashboard.heroku.com/new?button-url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevcenter.heroku.com%2Farticles%2Fmean-apps-restful-api&template=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fchrisckchang%2Fmean-contactlist) is an example to do so.
**[Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api)** is the full description step by step.